# CISCO Tc Bc and CIR units

Tags: cisco, qos

Are the units in these formulas correct?

```
Tc (seconds) = Bc (bits) / CIR (bits per second)
Tc (milliseconds) = Tc (seconds) * 1000
Bc (bits) = Tc (seconds) * CIR (bits per second)
CIR (bits per second) / Tc (seconds)
```

Comment: You may consider posting some more information on what you want to be sure about, you seem to be posting a screenshot of some chat without any explanation.

Comment: I wanted to make sure that the units are correct, I am trying to help someone.

Comment: That person in the screenshot is me actually, I have 0 knowledge about this topic hence my question on the units, all I did was simple algebra.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Copy the text, then paste it into the question, and use the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

All the units you mentioned is correct except the value of Tc(ms). It is creating confusion for layman like me :). You can write this as below :-

So Tc(ms) = [Bc(bits) / CIR (bits per second)] / 1000 -- > This makes sense that now Bc(bits) / CIR (bits per second) will give value in seconds which then divided by 1000 will produce value in ms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though I think you've made a mistake concerning the seconds to milliseconds conversion, 1s = 1000ms